# Nested Sub Projects in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

Is there a way to change the project listing so that sub projects display as nested items below their parent?

I have looked in the documentation and searched here, but cannot find anything.

At present the display of projects is either alphabetical or by creation date and doesn't differentiate between projects and sub projects.

It would be useful to be able to group projects in teh list under their master project.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The Subprojects feature is still in development, so stuff might still change over the coming months.

---

There isn't a *built-in* way to do what you're asking, but that doesn't mean there isn't a way. For example, I often list the master project in the subproject's name, in brackets. (i.e. "Goldilocks [PawLIB]") This allows me to create and save a Projects query for those projects with "[PawLIB]" in the name.

There are a few other ways to approach the issue, such as strategic use of project icons or colors (queries can search by those).

**In short, organize your projects using names, icons, or colors, and then set up a query.** This does not nullify the usefulness of the subproject feature - that handles many trickier organization in the background - but the feature as it exists can't do everything.

---

Aside from that, you could *technically* request a feature, but I wouldn't recommend it. Developer Chad Little mentioned that the features are backlogged by about two years. All things considered, they have bigger fish to fry.